# CUPS filter (C++) doesn't run until to end

Tags: c++, linux, printing, g++, cups

I'm working on a CUPS filter in C++ (g++ as compiler). The code is a authentication process and a only can release the job if the authentication is correct. If it's wrong, I have to cancel the print job.

When I print a document and the filter works, it runs a bunch of code in the authentication process, but suddenly, he stops works. If I comment a piece of code (doesn't matter what piece is), it runs correct a little more at the sequence of authentication. 
I tested the code when I split then, and the flow works fine.

There are a possible cause for this bug - a stack size limit, a time limit or other common bug?

Thanks.

**Code:**

Waiting for response of authentication (Java creates a data file)

```
/** Start monitor of authentication response **/

time_t starttime, now;
time(&starttime);

pthread_t thread_id = starttime;
pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &FileManager, NULL);

do{
    sleep(1);
    time(&now);
}while(!file_available && difftime(now, starttime) < config.GetJobTimeout());

pthread_cancel(thread_id);
```

...

```
ReturningJob returningJob;
returningJob.Execute(path + expected_filename);
```

ReturningJob file

```
this->Fill(filepath);

std::string xml = this->GetSerializedXML();
this->SaveFile(this->GenerateFilename(path), xml);
```

Comment: Can you make a [simple and minimal example](http://sscce.org/) program?

Comment: If it doesn't matter what you comment, then comment all but one line.  Once that works, do one more.